# List stays populated after PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, postback, viewstate

I have a .aspx application where the user inputs a name and that name is added to a list.  This can be done up to five times.  When the user clicks the button, the first name entered will display in the first label.  When the user inputs another name and clicks the button the first label remains the same and the next label displays the new name and so on.  My problem is the list is reset on PostBack.  I am trying to use ViewState to help solve this with no success.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:  I got it working so thank you everybody for your help.  There is still a lot of room for improvement but this is a great starting point.

```
       [Serializable]
    class Recipient
    {
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        public string MInit { get; set; }
        public string Lname { get; set; }
        public string Suffix { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Recipient recipients = new Recipient();

        List<string> FName = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];
        List<string> MInit = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];
        List<string> LName = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];


        if (FName == null && MInit == null && LName == null)
        {
            FName = new List<string>();
            MInit = new List<string>();
            LName = new List<string>();
        }

        recipients.Fname = txtFName.Text;
        recipients.MInit = txtMinit.Text;
        recipients.Lname = txtLName.Text;
        FName.Add(recipients.Fname);
        MInit.Add(recipients.MInit);
        LName.Add(recipients.Lname);
        ViewState["recipientList"] = FName;
        ViewState["recipientList"] = MInit;
        ViewState["recipientList"] = LName;

        if (FName.Count == 1 && MInit.Count == 1 && LName.Count == 1)
        {
            lblFName.Text = FName[0] + " " + MInit[0] + " " + LName[0];
        }

        if (FName.Count == 4 && MInit.Count == 4 && LName.Count == 4)
        {
            lblFName1.Text = FName[1] + " " + MInit[2] + " " + LName[3];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the purpose of Recipient class. Anyhow, you want to instantiate Recipient list before adding a recipient.

[image]

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFName" /><br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnEnter" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnEnter_Click" /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFName" /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFName1" /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFName2" /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFName3" /><br />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFName4" /><br />

[Serializable]
public class Recipient
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public List<Recipient> recipientList
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["recipientList"] != null)
            return (List<Recipient>)ViewState["recipientList"];
        return new List<Recipient>();
    }
    set { ViewState["recipientList"] = value; }
}

protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Recipient> recipient = recipientList;
    recipient.Add(new Recipient{ name = txtFName.Text.Trim()});
    recipientList = recipient;

    int count = recipient.Count;

    if (count == 1)
        lblFName.Text = recipientList[0].name;

    if (count > 1)
        lblFName1.Text = recipientList[1].name;

    if (count > 2)
        lblFName2.Text = recipientList[2].name;

    if (count > 3)
        lblFName3.Text = recipientList[3].name;

    if (count > 4)
        lblFName4.Text = recipientList[4].name;
}
```

Comment: I got it working (see above) however I like how you have done it as well.  This version may help with error handling better as well as the user editing information.  Thanks a lot, I will try to incorporate what you have done.

Comment: Just noticed you are in Wichita.  I live in Andover myself so thanks neighbor!

Comment: It's a small world. ;) If you have any questions, just holla at me. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a list for this?  You could do...

```
if(lblFName.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
{
    lblFName.Text = value;
}
else if(lblFName1.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
{
    lblFName1.Text = value;
}//and so on...
```

Comment: I tried something similar to that in the beginning with no luck.  From what I can see after doing this is that a list is probably the best option.  This project will expand to use multiple textboxes as well as dropdown lists.  I just wanted to get this part working before proceeding to the larger portion of the project.  I also know that ViewState will eat up a lot of resources however it is in the best interest to use it.

Comment: recipientList = recipient;
might be the issue, shouldn't it be recipientList.AddRange(recipient)

Comment: It does work, however on postback it does not retain the name in the list so only the first label is populated no matter how many times a new name is added.

Answer (score 0):

If a postback is firing when you hit the enter button. Then you need to handle rebuilding the list in the Page_Load. Something like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        recipientList = (List<string>)ViewState["recipientList"];

        //now load the list
    }
  }
```